# SQL select only highest date

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, select, subquery

For a project I want to generate a price list.
I want to get only the latest prices from each supplier for each article.

There are just those two tables.

```
Table articles

 ARTNR  | TXT           | ACTIVE    | SUPPLIER
 ------------------------------------------
 10     | APPLE         | Y         | 10
 20     | ORANGE        | Y         | 10
 30     | KEYBOARD      | N         | 20
 40     | ORANGE        | Y         | 20
 50     | BANANA        | Y         | 10
 60     | CHERRY        | Y         | 10


Table prices
 ARTNR  | PRCGRP    | PRCDAT    | PRICE
 --------------------------------------
 10     | 10        | 01-Aug-10 | 2.1
 10     | 10        | 05-Aug-11 | 2.2
 10     | 10        | 21-Aug-12 | 2.5
 20     | 0         | 01-Aug-10 | 2.1
 20     | 10        | 09-Aug-12 | 2.3
 10     | 10        | 14-Aug-13 | 2.7
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    ARTICLES.[ARTNR], ARTICLES.[TXT], ARTICLES.[ACTIVE], ARTICLES.[SUPPLIER],   PRICES.PRCGRP, PRICES.PRCDAT, PRICES.PRICE
FROM 
    ARTICLES INNER JOIN PRICES ON ARTICLES.ARTNR = PRICES.ARTNR
WHERE 
    (
    (ARTICLES.[ACTIVE]="Y") AND 
    (ARTICLES.[SUPPLIER]=10) AND 
    (PRICES.PRCGRP=0) AND
    (PRICES.PRCDAT=(SELECT MAX(PRCDAT) FROM PRICES as art WHERE art.ARTNR =     PRICES.artnr) )
    )
ORDER BY ARTICLES.ARTNR
;
```

It is okay to choose just one supplier each time, but I want the max price.

**The problem is:**
Lots of articles do not show up with the query above, 
but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I can see that they should be in the resultset when I leave out the subselect on max prcdat.

What is wrong?

Comment: Change `WHERE art.ARTNR = PRICES.artnr` to `WHERE art.ARTNR = ARTICLES.artnr`

Comment: @Mihai Thank you for your comment.Have tried that, but had the same result with missing articles.

Comment: One easy way is to repeat the WHERE conditions in the subquery.

Comment: Have done that, but now only the highest date of all is considered, not the highest date of the one article.

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery to get the latest price does not take the other conditions into account, that is when you're getting the latest price, you may get a price in another price group or that is not active. When you join that against the filtered list that has no inactive prices and only prices in a single price group, you get no hits that exist in both.

Either you need to duplicate or - better - move your conditions inside the subquery to get the best price under the conditions. I can't test against access, but something like this *should* be possible if the SQL is not too limited;

```sql
SELECT a.artnr, a.txt, a.active, a.supplier, p.prcgrp, p.prcdat, p.price
FROM articles a INNER JOIN prices p ON a.ARTNR = p.ARTNR
JOIN (
  SELECT a.artnr, MAX(p.prcdat) prcdat
  FROM articles a JOIN prices p ON a.artnr = p.artnr
  WHERE a.active='Y' AND a.supplier=10 AND p.prcgrp=10
  GROUP BY a.artnr) z
ON a.artnr = z.artnr AND p.prcdat = z.prcdat
ORDER BY a.ARTNR
```

If the SQL support in access won't allow a join with a subquery, you can just move the conditions inside your existing subquery, something like;

```
SELECT a.artnr, a.txt, a.active, a.supplier, p.prcgrp, p.prcdat, p.price
FROM articles a INNER JOIN prices p ON a.ARTNR = p.ARTNR
WHERE p.prcdat = (
   SELECT MAX(p2.prcdat) 
   FROM articles a2 JOIN prices p2 ON a2.artnr = p2.artnr
   WHERE a.artnr = a2.artnr AND a2.active='Y' AND a2.supplier=10 AND p2.prcgrp=10
)
ORDER BY a.ARTNR;
```

Note that due to limitations in identifying a unique price (no primary key in prices), the queries may give duplicates if several prices for the same article have the same prcdat. If that's a problem, you'll probably need to duplicate your conditions outside the subquery too.

Comment: You are right. I missed the way to get the latest price for what I want. With your query I get a "missing operator" error for the part after a.artnr=p.artnr join...

Comment: @MareInfinitus Added an alternative with a regular subquery.

Comment: Thank you very much. Right now I have a syntax error in the subquery part beginning from "p.prcdat =". But it all looks like perfectly legal SQL. I do not like access very much...